# Why is my entire webpage shifting on keypress in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, carousel

I am using [the Unslider plugin](http://www.unslider.com) on [this website](http://energy-solutions.herokuapp.com).

Every time I press the <kbd>></kbd> (right key), the entire page (probably the `body` element) moves 25 pixels to the right.

Every time I press the <kbd><</kbd> (left key), the entire page moves back to its normal position.

You can see the issue live here:

http://energy-solutions.herokuapp.com

Here is the `html.erb` file:

```
<div class="imagecarousel has-dots">
    <ul>
        <li style='background-image: url("/assets/solar-18694222104b6ced788b349cd63f53cc.jpg")'>
            <div class="caption">
                <h1>Renewable Energy.</h1>
                <p>The future is in our hands.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style='background-image: url("/assets/wind-eaac506eb1ae1d11c572e1bec4b04ca2.jpg");'>
            <div class="caption">
                <h1>Renewable Energy.</h1>
                <p>Energy is beautiful.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style='background-image: url("/assets/geothermal-58b3e2d8eeb063847de79d733f7611e0.jpg");'>
            <div class="caption">
                <h1>Renewable Energy.</h1>
                <p>Clean. Safe. Efficient.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style='background-image: url("/assets/solar-46b6cfecb2169a3d14552f90196a56fb.jpg");'>
            <div class="caption">
                <h1>Renewable Energy.</h1>
                <p>The world needs it.</p>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style='background-image: url("/assets/solarpanels-c787e429912f640d7770f1cc482073ad.jpg");'>
            <div class="caption">
                <h1>Renewable Energy.</h1>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style='background-image: url("/assets/wind-ee6159e5689bd3475afc83cefc876069.jpg");'>
            <div class="caption">
                <h1>Renewable Energy.</h1>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And here is how I call it in my `application.js`:

```
$('.imagecarousel').unslider({
        fluid: true,
        dots: true,
        keys: true,
        speed: 500
    });
```

Any ideas? It only happens on this page, so I am assuming it has something to do with the image carousel.

**Edit:** The issue only appears in Firefox. Chrome and Safari do not seem to have this issue.

Please let me know if I should post any more code that might be relevant to solving this issue.

Comment: How have I answered my question? I do not know how to resolve this problem.

Comment: your website works fine in Chrome

Comment: Then it seems to be a Firefox only issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code seemed to solve the issue. This may not be the proper way to fix this, but it seems to work in all browsers now.

```
html{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
head{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```